# Splitting contents of one sql column into 3 columns based on certain characters that always happen in the value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to form a SQL query, using SQL Server 2014 without creating a function.  I do not have permissions on the database to create functions so I have to do it with a query only.

I have a column named `Test` with the example value of:

```
Accounting -> Add Missing functionality in Payable -> Saving a blank Missing row
```

I want my query to return the information (of varying length) between the two arrows (`->`). I have tried the right, left, substring, charindex and patindex functions and various combinations of each.

Basically the query needs to be `SUBSTRING(Test, CHARINDEX(' -> ', TEST) +3, <some length here>)`

The length is the part I'm having a hard time figuring out. I need the full length minus the first part before and including the first `->` which evaluates to:

```
Add Missing functionality in Payable -> Saving a blank Missing row
```

From that result, I need to remove everything after and including the `->`, which would then leave me with:

```
Add Missing functionality in Payable
```

At the end of the day, I want to split this one column up into 3 like so:

```
Domain     | Feature                              | Test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Accounting | Add Missing functionality in Payable | Saving a blank Missing row
```

---

Can anyone show me how to do this query, without having to write a function?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on this one portion of the query for the better part of 4 hours now.  Thank you in advance for your help.  Have a great day!!

Comment: Thank you TT for making this look the way I wanted it to, to begin with - appreciate it.  I've reviewed the changes you made and now will know how to do that in the  future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following query and it is woking fine for me:

```
DECLARE @X as varchar(1000) 

SET @X = 'Accounting -> Add Missing functionality in Payable -> Saving a blank Missing row'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@X,1,CHARINDEX('->',@X) - 1) AS Domain,
SUBSTRING(@X,CHARINDEX('->',@X)  + 2,LEN(SUBSTRING(@X,CHARINDEX('->',@X)  + 2,LEN(@X))) - LEN(SUBSTRING(@X,LEN(@X) - CHARINDEX('>-',REVERSE(@X))  ,LEN(@X))))  AS Feature,
SUBSTRING(@X,LEN(@X) - CHARINDEX('>-',REVERSE(@X)) + 2 ,LEN(@X)) AS Test
```

You have to use this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Test],1,CHARINDEX('->',[Test]) - 1) AS Domain,
SUBSTRING([Test],CHARINDEX('->',[Test])  + 2,LEN(SUBSTRING([Test],CHARINDEX('->',[Test])  + 2,LEN([Test]))) - LEN(SUBSTRING([Test],LEN([Test]) - CHARINDEX('>-',REVERSE([Test]))  ,LEN([Test]))))  AS Feature,
SUBSTRING([Test],LEN([Test]) - CHARINDEX('>-',REVERSE([Test])) + 2 ,LEN([Test])) AS Test
FROM MyTable  --Replace MyTable with your table name
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for your help with this.  I could not get the Feature part of this working to save my life.  I so very much appreciate it!!